# UI framework design: different approaches to determine preselected item in a list?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, user-interface

Something I've been wondering about: if I was to implement some kind of list like UI widget (no specific target platform is assumed here, but I'm using C# to illustrate), I can see three ways of determining the preselected entry in my list.
Look at the stubs below. All three implementations have a delegate that asks the implementation for the items to be displayed instead of passing the items in directly. The idea is that the items will only be requested if the UI element actually is about to be displayed.

The first implementation has a setter that allows defining the preselected item.

```
public class ListWidget<T>
{
  public Action<IList<T>> GetListItems;

  public SetPreselectedItem(T item)
  {
    this.preselectedItem = item;
  }
}
```

or:

This follows the idea that the list widget at some point asks the implementation - by looping all the items it knows - if an item should be preselected or not. Advantage I see here: it would allow multi selection.

```
public class ListWidget<T>
{
  public Action<IList<T>> GetListItems;

  public Action<bool> IsItemPreselected(T item);
}
```

or:

This is asking the implementation for the the preselected item whenever it needs to render its contents.

```
public class ListWidget<T>
{
  public Action<IList<T>> GetListItems;

  public T GetPreselectedItem();
}
```

If I look at Apple's UIKit, they kind of use the first approach: the list is asking for the data to be displayed but the selected item is set directly.
The problem I see with a setter and the last version: you can set any value, even if that item does not exist in the list. It requires either an extra check if the item to be set actually exists in the list.
I have seen all variations of the patterns above on different platforms but I'm wondering if there is a best approach? Or is there yet another version of implementing it?